# Gridbag Layout in java

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have to edit a gridbag layout problematically and i am having weird results.
expected:
| A | | B |
| -- | | C |
| D | | -- |

Results:
| A | | B |
| D | | C |

A and C have a height of 2
Is this just how gridbag works? is there anyway to force it?

My program has two columns  and n number of rows. It supports a width of 2 but it only comes into effect when it is in the first col. If in the 2nd row it acts as though the width is 1.

`gbc.gridx = 0;

        gbc.gridy = 0;

        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;

        gbc.weighty = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.insets = new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7);

        gbc.weightx = 0.5;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;`

the components are added by the user and the user determines the `width` and `height`. the `gridx`and `gridy` values are determined by what other components are added and placed.

The gridbag layout works fine for say
*_ _
|A|B|
|_|C|
it just doesn't seem to like it when C has a height of 2

Comment: You should post some code so we see what you are trying to do.

Comment: hmm. let me see if i can clean up the method to be slightly more general. 

for now let me try to explain it some:
(heights and widths represent gridbag constraints)
I have several user created tables with heights 1-10 and widths 1-2

Comment: Can you show some screen shots and some code? The question as is is too abstract.

Comment: Post the GridbagConstraints for the components.

Comment: posted the gridbag constraints in the question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting `GridbagConstraints.BOTH` for your `fill` property of the `GridbagConstraints` object you are using. Otherwise, you won't be able to have components on multiple rows.

```
GridbagConstraints c = new GridbagConstraints();
c.fill = GridbagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear with my example A and C are components with a height of 2

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question has been clarified:

```
protected static final Insets entryInsets = new Insets(0, 10, 4, 10);
protected static final Insets spaceInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 4, 10);

protected void createPartControl() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    int gridy = 0;
    gridy = createTextFields(gridy);
}

protected int createTextFields(int gridy) {
    JLabel a = new JLabel("A");
    a.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    addComponent(panel, a, 0, gridy, 1, 2, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JLabel b = new JLabel("B");
    b.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    addComponent(panel, b, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JLabel c = new JLabel("C");
    c.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    addComponent(panel, c, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, entryInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JLabel d = new JLabel("D");
    d.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    addComponent(panel, d, 0, gridy++, 2, 1, entryInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    return gridy;
}

protected void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
        int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
        Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
            gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```